# Why does the Skin in my AVD not show the contol/keyboard/menu section?

Tags: android, skin

How can I build a standard ADV to test my Hello World app. I've just built my Hello World app on Android - using eclipse, and am having real problems getting the AVD to work properly.   My setup Android 3.1 level 12, and I set the skin to 800 x 600 as the default WXGA, seem to make a massive screen. When it loads, I get just the Android screen but no side keyboard.

In addition, why do I get completely different looking skins when I play around with the skin size. Sometimes, I get a nice sea scape sometimes, but its portrait not landscape - how do I turn it? One time I get a lock?

Any help would be really appreciated. (I using Java 1.6 64 bit).

Thank you very much.

Ed Ryan

Answer (score 2):

> My setup Android 3.1 level 12, and I set the skin to 800 x 600 as the default WXGA, seem to make a massive screen.

Use the scale option when launching the emulator to resize it to something manageable. There are no 800x600 Honeycomb devices, so you are far better served using WXGA.

> When it loads, I get just the Android screen but no side keyboard.

Correct. You won't get the side keyboard for WXGA, either. You do not need it, as everything on that side keyboard is available to you [from your own physical keyboard on your development machine](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#controlling).

Answer (score 0):

The skins are only available for the out-of-the-box skins or the ones you create manually (see [here](http://heikobehrens.net/2011/03/15/android-skins/)). However, you can access all of the keys using other [keyboard shortcuts](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html), which I personally found way more convenient. Plus, you save space.

Comment: Hi Dmon, Thank you for responding.